# Como mostrar quantidade de vendas por forma de pagamento por mes no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tendo o seguinte resultado:

```
Mes | QtdPorMes
 1  |    124
 2  |    102
 3  |    84
 4  |    32
```

Precisaria que ficasse assim:

```
 Mes |   Boleto  | Cartão  | Total
  1  |     100   |   24    |  124
  2  |     82    |   20    |  82   
  3  |     34    |   50    |  84   
  4  |     12    |   20    |  32
```

Quais cláusulas eu deveria usar?

A tabela é fictícia, apenas para estudos.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataVenda) AS 'Mes',
    COUNT(FormaPagamento) AS 'QtdPorMes'
FROM
    vendas
WHERE
    DataVenda > '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(DataVenda)
ORDER BY MONTH(DataVenda);
```

Comment: Qual estrutura da tabela vendas? E como você diferencia a forma de pagamento?

Comment: A estrutura da tabela vendas: CodVenda INT, DataVenda DATE, ValorVenda DECIMAL, FormaPagamento INT. (FormaPagamento 1 = Boleto, 2 = Cartão)

Comment: Gabriel, isso é uma informação relevante que deveria estar na pergunta. Você pode editá-la e incluir =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Montei um exemplo, veja se te atende:

```
create table tempVendas
(
    DataVenda datetime,
    FormaPagamento varchar(100)
)

insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-01-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-01-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-01-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-01-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-01-01', 'Cartão')

insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-02-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-02-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-02-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-02-01', 'Cartão')

insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Boleto')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Cartão')
insert into  tempVendas values ('2018-03-01', 'Cartão')


SELECT month(dataVenda) [Mes],
count(case when FormaPagamento = 'Boleto' then FormaPagamento end) 'Boleto',
count(case when FormaPagamento = 'Cartão' then FormaPagamento end) 'Cartão',
count(FormaPagamento) Total
FROM tempVendas
group by month(dataVenda)
order by month(dataVenda)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c28a/2

Answer (score 1):

Você conseguiria o resultado esperado com a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataVenda) AS 'Mes',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendas V2 WHERE V2.DataVenda > '2018-01-01' AND MONTH(V2.DataVenda) = V1.DataVenda AND FormaPagamento = 1) as 'Boleto',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendas V2 WHERE V2.DataVenda > '2018-01-01' AND MONTH(V2.DataVenda) = V1.DataVenda AND FormaPagamento = 2) as 'Cartão', 
    COUNT(FormaPagamento) AS 'QtdPorMes'
FROM
    vendas V1
WHERE
    DataVenda > '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(DataVenda)
ORDER BY MONTH(DataVenda);
```

---

Porém assim você precisa executar *subconsultas*. Se possível, sugiro usar o código abaixo e montar o `QtdPorMes` total via código:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataVenda) AS 'Mes',
    FormaPagamento, 
    COUNT(FormaPagamento) AS 'QtdPorMesForma'
FROM
    vendas V1
WHERE
    DataVenda > '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(DataVenda), FormaPagamento
ORDER BY MONTH(DataVenda);
```

Assim, o retorno seria algo como abaixo:

> ```
>  Mes | FormaPagamento | QtdPorMesForma
>   1  |         1      |       100
>   1  |         2      |       24    
>   2  |         1      |       62
>   2  |         2      |       20
>   3  |         1      |       34
>   3  |         2      |       50    
>   4  |         1      |       12
>   4  |         2      |       20
> ```

Comment: Na segunda forma o resultado seria 3 colunas e 2 linhas (boleto/cartão) para cada mes? Algo assim:
`Mes | Forma | Qtd
  1   |  Boleto |  5
  1   |  Cartão |  8
  2   |  Boleto |  4
  2   |  Cartão |  12`

Comment: editei a resposta, veja se ficou claro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(DataVenda) AS 'Mes',
    Sum( CASE WHEN FormaPagamento = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Boleto',
    Sum( CASE WHEN FormaPagamento = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cartão',       
    Sum( CASE WHEN FormaPagamento <> 1 AND FormaPagamento <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Outros',      
    COUNT(*) AS 'QtdTotal'
FROM
    vendas
WHERE
    DataVenda > '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(DataVenda)
ORDER BY MONTH(DataVenda);
```

*Note que eu já incluí uma coluna adicional 'Outros' para o caso de a forma de pagamento ser diferente de 1 e 2.*

O problema é que a cada nova forma de pagamento que você precisar incluir como coluna, esse select precisará ser alterado.